# xm destroy command hangs indefinitely

Tags: xen

Dear Community Members,

I have a situation here ! One of the VM running on OVS 3.2.11 is stuck and I tried to kill it from OVMM but that didn't work. I also tried to use xm destroy command but it hangs indefinitely.

Could you please share your thoughts on how to debug, where to look the logs(I have checked all the default log locations) but no clue. Could you please share what could have been wrong with this VM. All the other VMs responds normal.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi. Please provide some more details about your approaches with debbugin and maybe about your vm. Detailed informations are relevant for people willing to help.